# Trying to write a bash file to find specific pattern of string and replace with new string from command line arg using shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I am trying write a bash file to find a string in a .txt file using shell script and want to replace same with new string.

The string pattern which I am trying find `{{asdf}}` and I want to replace it with `ghjk` from command line arg.

I tried with the following bash file:

```
ptr="\{\{(.*?)\}\}"
username="$1"
password="$2"
sed 's/$ptr/${username}/g' new.txt
sed 's/$ptr/${password}/g' sec.txt
```

but it's not working.

Comment: ptr="\{\{(.*?)\{\{" this is the regex pattern I am using.

Comment: sed doesn't support non-greedy... use `[^}]*` instead of `.*?` .. you need to use [double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sed/1096/substitution/3519/substitution-using-shell-variables#t=20170416062029431247) for variable substitution...

Comment: I think your looking for the `-i` option (in-place).

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Please edit your question and be specific.

Answer (score 0):

You need double codes before the vars will be replaced by their values.
With a `+` telling at least once, you can use

```
ptr="{{.\+}}"
sed "s/$ptr/${username}/g" usertemplate.txt > new.txt
```

Using `sed` for the password will be a challenge in view of the special characters (don't tell others, my password is `/\\[.*&{7z`).
You can try something like

```
ptr="{{.\+}}"
username='/\\[.*&{7z'
escapedname=$(sed 's/[&=\/|]/\\&/g'  <<< "$username")
sed "s/$ptr/${escapedname}/g" usertemplate.txt
```

Edit: I first tried to escape most characters, but that was to hard for me.
I changed it into a minimal version. I hope this one is better.

Comment: That will fail if `{{foo}` (one `}`) appears in the input. For robustness you need to match on `}}` and find a way to negate `}}` between `{{` and `}}` so it doesn't match on `{{foo}}bar}}` but does match on `{{foo}bar}}`.

Comment: To strengthen the point about escaping: Try this username unescaped `username="/g;e echo "hello"; #"`. Do not try `username="/g ;e rm -rf \*; #"`

Answer (score 0):

one thing you should note is that `''` single quotes have special meaning in shell programming. Single quotes negates a variable i.e they don't allow you to access the content of the variable but just the name of the variable.

What you need to do , is to remove the single quotes `'s/$ptr/${username}/g'` and wrap with with double quotes i.e `"s/$ptr/${username}/g"`.

Better still if you wish to use single quotes, you should use here strings just as [walter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3220113/walter-a) specified. Here strings can be done with `<<<`. If you decide to use here strings, the logic of the code will change totally.

Answer (score -1):

Just use awk:

```
username="$1" awk '
{
    gsub(/}}/,"\n")
    delete a
    if ( match($0,/{{[^\n]+\n/) ) {
        a[1] = substr($0,1,RSTART-1)
        a[2] = ENVIRON["username"]
        a[3] = substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
    }
    else {
        a[1] = $0
    }
    gsub(/\n/,"}}",a[1])
    gsub(/\n/,"}}",a[3])
    print a[1] a[2] a[3]
}
' new.txt
```

The above will work for any value of `username` and will not fail if/when `{{foo}` (just one `}`) appears in the input. Repeat for password. It's important to set the shell variable `username` on the awk command line exactly as shown so it's available to awk via the ENVIRON array without needing to export it.

Comment: This may be a working answer, but it A) Does not help OP fix any of his issues and B) replaces three lines with a ~15 line monstrosity.

Comment: @MadPhysicist A) Of course it does, this is THE way to do what the OP needs to do, what more do you want? B) Hardly a monstrosity, the code couldn't be much simpler and as is usually the case to do something robustly simply does take more lines of code than to do something fragile that will come back to bite you later. You will notice there is no other functional answer posted. Why do you think that is? I personally could post a robust shell+sed solution but it'd be an incomprehensible mush of characters and just pointless since what I have posted is better in every meaningful way.